# How to get the HTTP Request body content in a Spring Boot Filter?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to get the raw content that is posted towards a RestController. I need it to do some processing on the raw input.

How can I get the raw body content without interfering with the Filter Chain?

Comment: Easiest way would be to use `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ModelAttribute` method to access it. Why not use a controller advice as it is a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Could be a solution indeed. Did not think of that. I am not sure if it possible. I need to get data from the HTTP-Headers and the Raw posted content.Could you give an example how the @ModelAttribute could help me out in getting the data i need?

Comment: Gave it as an answer as formatting is too complicated on comment section. Let me know if helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a sample of controllerAdvice where you can access RequestBody and RequestHeader as you do in your controller. The Model attribute method is basically to add model attributes which are used across all pages or controller flow. It gets invoked before the controller methods kick in. It provides cleaner way of accessing the RESTful features rather than convoluted way.

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
public class ControllerAdvisor {

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addAttributes(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,Model model, @RequestBody String requestString, @RequestHeader(value = "User-Agent") String userAgent) {
        // do whatever you want to do on the request body and header. 
        // with request object you can get the request method and request path etc.
        System.out.println("requestString" + requestString);
        System.out.println("userAgent" + userAgent);
        model.addAttribute("attr1", "value1");
        model.addAttribute("attr2", "value2");
    }   

}
```

Comment: I am going to test this for sure, could you elaborate a bit on how @ModelAttribute works? Or point out a good example? I checked the Spring documentation but still cannot figure out how it works.

Comment: Would it also be possible to get to the requested url and HTTP method that is used?

Comment: @ModelAttribute method takes pretty much same kind of arguments as that of a controller method. I have not tried them all. I have edited the answer to take a HttpServletRequest. You can get the request url and request method from request object.

Comment: When implementing the controller advice i see that is execute 2 times, is this intented?

Comment: As far as i know, it should. How did you conclude that it is invoked twice?

Comment: I was my mistake.. I did a new test and indeed it only passes once!

Comment: Please advise that this is going to consume the Request - next processing (the controller) will receive nothing.

Comment: Nope. It won't consume the request. Spring will continue to pass the request to the controller behind the advice.

Comment: @minion I think Luca is correct... I keep getting an empty body error in next processing (the controller)

Answer (score 2):

I use @ModelAttribute method to set value from @RequestBody.

```
@ControllerAdvice 
public class CustomRestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler 
{


    public CustomRestExceptionHandler() {
        super();
    }

    private Object request;

    @ModelAttribute
    public void setRequest(@RequestBody Object request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        logger.info(this.request)
    }

}
```